# give bootup messages and times, embedded linux

Tags: embedded-linux

i had problem to show bootup steps and each step's time in an embedded linux project on cubieboard2. so i solved the problem using grabserial. to do so follow below instructions:

1- download grabserial from: https://github.com/tbird20d/grabserial

2- extract downloaded files and go to extracted directory

3- make grabserial file executable using below script in the terminal:

```
              Sudo chmod +x grabserial
```

4- install required packages using below script:

```
              sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

5- do below copy:

```
              sudo cp grabserial /usr/local/bin
```

6- exit from the extracted folder using cd /..

7- connect your device to your PC using com0 port.

8- type below script in the terminal to save output of com0 port into bootTime.txt file.

```
              sudo grabserial  -d /dev/ttyS0 -m RomBoot -t -e 30 &>>bootTime.txt
```

9- if you want to show bootTime.txt content in the terminal, open a new terminal and type below script:

```
            tailf bootTime.txt
```

Comment: Was there a programming question or is this just a how to? If so, it doesn't belong to SO.

Comment: no, it was a problem i faced with and i decided to share my solution to others!

Comment: Then you need to put it into a suitable site. SO is for programming, which I don't see here. Also you have to make it into a question and an answer. Please read the help section.